# BlackBerry adding scrollchangelistener to mainscreen not working

Tags: blackberry

```
public class EventListScreen extends MainScreen implements ScrollChangeListener{
...

}
```

then in the constructor I added

```
setScrollListener(this);
```

and of course I implemented

```
public void scrollChanged(Manager manager, int newHorizontalScroll,int newVerticalScroll) {
```

Originally, I had everything added to a verticalfieldmanager which was added to the mainscreen, but I couldnt get the listener working with that. I've gotten a scrollChangelistener working before with a horizontalfieldmanager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set scroll listener to main manager `MainScreen.getMainManager()`.